# C++ XML library heavily utilizing operator overloading

Tags: c++, xml, operator-overloading

Some time ago I saw a XML library for C++ which heavily utilized operator overloading, allowing for *cute* syntax similar to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <some_xml_library/some_header.hpp>

using namespace some_xml_library;

int main()
{
    elem_t div;
    doc_t d = _ <div>"hello"<!div> _;

    std::cout << d;
}
```

Output:

```
<div>hello</div>
```

IIRC the library also had full support for attributes and nested elements.

Have I dreamt this, or does anyone know what this library is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/?p=115)?